# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to load data from file which was in main bundle. When I use this code

```
 let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "abc", ofType: "txt")
 let dataTwo = try! Data(contentsOf: path)\\ error here
```

Also I tried to convert String to URL

```
 let dataTwo = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "file://\(path)")!)
```

But after execution am getting this

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Are you sure the files you're trying to load are included in your bundle ? It's not enough to put them in your project's folder, you have to instruct Xcode to actually copy them in the bundle.

Comment: I am damn sure it was there only. Also I checked in Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases

Comment: You could check in the generated bundle to see if the files are really there ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use `.url` instead:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "abc", withExtension:"txt")
let dataTwo = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
```

and safely handle errors instead of force unwrapping.

Simple version:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "abc", withExtension:"txt"),
    let dataTwo = try? Data(contentsOf: url) 
{
    // use dataTwo
} else {
    // some error happened
}
```

Even better:

```
do {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "abc", withExtension:"txt") else {
        return
    }
    let dataTwo = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    // use dataTwo
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This way you don't need to convert a path to an URL, because you're using an URL from the beginning, and you can handle errors. In your specific case, you will know if your asset is there and if your URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For file URL use [init(fileURLWithPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1780183-init) constructor.

Also here

```
let dataTwo = try! Data(contentsOf: path)\\ error here
```

get rid of `try!` and use proper error handling to see whats the real error happens.