# cannot convert value of type "String" to expected argument type "URL"

Tags: swift, sqlite

The statement in `do` is not being executed. Anyone can help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!

```
class func copyFile(fileName: NSString){

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    guard documentsURL.count != 0 else{
        return
    }

    let finalDatabaseURL = documentsURL.first!.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

    if !((try? finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false){
        print("Database does not exist in documents")

        let documentsURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

        do{
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: (documentsURL?.path)!, to: finalDatabaseURL.path)

        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Couldn't copy file to final location!Error:\(error.description)")
        }
    }else{
        print("Database file found at path:\(finalDatabaseURL.path)")
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'URL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360716/cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-url)

Answer (score 0):

`copyItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL)` takes both URL parameters and you are passing strings.

Either you use this.

```
try fileManager.copyItem(at: documentsURL!, to: finalDatabaseURL)
```

or

```
try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: (documentsURL?.path)!, toPath: finalDatabaseURL.path)
```